# Mac Pro 64-bit addressing kernel

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard, kernel, 32bit-64bit

I am wondering about an app I am developing and 64-bit addressing.  I would like to use around 12 GB of 32 GB available on a Mac Pro.

Here's the thing, the kernel is not 64-bit in Snow Leopard on my Mac Pro (efi 32-bit).  I am wondering though if I will be able to address that much ram, >4GB per application, even if the kernel is only 32-bit.

It's basically for map data, and the set is around 12 GB, and I want it running fast... no page swapping.

Thanks for the help

Laters...

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can allocate >4 GB RAM within a 64-bit app on Snow Leopard (or Leopard or Tiger, for that matter).  The 64-bit vs 32-bit kernel does not make any difference.

Comment: Thanks, I thought so I heard different.  I practically skipped leopard (10.5) and stayed with tiger (10.4) and that was only command lines apps...